# MySQL group rows that share at least one value in common on multiple columns

Tags: mysql

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_identifiers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniqueness` (`order_id`,`email`,`phone`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `order` (`order_id`),
  KEY `phone` (`phone`),
  KEY `CA` (`created_at`),
  KEY `UA` (`updated_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into dev.customer_identifiers(order_id,email,phone) values (1,'test@gmail.com','07444226373'),
 (2,'test@gmail.com','0744422633'), 
 (3,'test2@gmail.com','07444226373'),
 (4,'test3@gmail.com','07453456373'), 
 (5,'test4@gmail.com','07955226373');
```

[image]

How could I group of all order ids that share either the same email or the same phone number?

desired output:

```
+----------+------------------------+--------------------------------+
| order_id | phone                  | mail                           |
+----------+------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 1,2,3    | 07444226373,0744422633 | test2@gmail.com,test@gmail.com |
+----------+------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 4        | 07453456373            | test3@gmail.com                |
+----------+------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 5        | 07955226373            | test4@gmail.com                |
+----------+------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: write a select to group by email and union it with a select grouping by phone

Comment: Hint:  maybe `GROUP_CONCAT`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2` and maybe `UNION ALL`.. Atleast provide us with a [text formatted](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) expected result based on the example data.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I updated the question with the desired output

Comment: Why are the order_id's 4 and 5 in the results?  It's not the same email or phone number..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I edited the title and replaced find with group. I hope it's clear what I'm after. Do you have a better idea to phrase this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT ci2.`order_id`,GROUP_CONCAT(ci2.`order_id`) AS `concats`,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ci2.`phone`) as phones,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ci2.`email`) as mails 
    FROM `customer_identifiers` ci1
    INNER JOIN `customer_identifiers` ci2 ON ci1.`email` = ci2.`email` OR ci1.`phone` = ci2.`phone`
    GROUP BY ci1.`order_id`
) AS tbl1 
GROUP BY tbl1.`order_id`;
```

Answer (score -1):

What you should do is to count the number of duplicated rows:

```
SELECT 
email,
phone,
COUNT(email) AS count_email,
COUNT(phone) AS count_phone
FROM customer_identifiers
GROUP BY email,phone
HAVING
COUNT(email)>1  OR COUNT(phone) > 1
```

You can personalize to return the columns you need to identify the ids that have the duplicity.

I hope it helps...

Comment: `WHERE COUNT(email)>1  OR COUNT(phone) > 1` is wrong It should be `HAVING COUNT(email)>1  OR COUNT(phone) > 1` instead

Comment: "You can personalize to return the columns you need." Besides you need to have a JOIN to get the **correct** order id's from the table..You can't just place order_id column in the select here and hope you get the correct results because you wont get those.